# In Laravel, storing values to a join table without defining Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

As part of the onboarding process for my Laravel app, a user can enter the ages of his or her children. A user can have many children, and so there needs to be a `kids` table that stores `id`, `user_id` (which references `id` on the `users` table), and `kid_age`. This seems like a basic one-to-many relationship—a user can have many children.

In a profile view elsewhere in the app, I have display back the ages of each child. However, that's the *only* point in the app where the kids make an appearance. It seems like overkill to create an entire `kid` model just to manage the parent to child relationship.

Is there a lighter-weight way to assign values to a join table? If so, how would I save data to that table without defining the relationship between two models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using a model, you'd have to manage the tables manually in the database.  I think it is far and away easier to use a model for this, so that you can create, update, delete, and sync `kid` models effortlessly using Laravel functions.  Because you've followed the proper naming conventions for tables and ID columns, it should only take a couple of lines of code to create the new model.  Seems light-weight enough to me.

Sorry for not providing another solution, but my take is go with the Laravel solution.